# Round Double value and exponential notation (java)

Tags: java, math, rounding

how to round "3.416436417734133 in "3.416436418" (nine positions after point) but also if i have "3.7578845854848E41" it round to "3.7578845855E41"? i'm trying to realyze a calculator..

Comment: Do you need to round the actual double value, or do you need to format it as a String for rendering with less precision?

Comment: @dotdav i need to format it

Comment: Then I suggest you look into `String.format()` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29

Comment: @dotdav but the value is double.. not string... so i think i need to round the actual double value (sorry)

Comment: `String.format` will format an `Object` into a `String` with the specification you give it. Read the doc, try it, and come back with any issue you may encounter.

Comment: What should be the output for `37578.845854848E41` or `34.5` ?

Comment: You seem to be trying to round strings, not doubles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html), I am not sure about the other numbers but currently you have numbers which have single digit before the decimal point. So, check following example where you can format the double value. Note one more thing that you may need to change format pattern for your use case.

***FOR EXAMPLE :***

```
double d = 3.7578845854848E41;
double d2 = 3.416436417734133;
DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("0.#########E0");
System.out.println(f.format(d));
System.out.println(f.format(d2));
```

***OUTPUT :***

```
3.757884585E41
3.416436418E0

//Replace E0 with space as format returns String
```

**EDIT :**

Because of your default locale. You can change local like this,

```
//Change locale
DecimalFormatSymbols decimalFormatSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.US);
DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("0.#########E0", decimalFormatSymbols);
//And than use decimal format
```

Comment: it works but there is "," instead of ".".... so i have "3,416436418E0" etc.... how replace "," to "."?

Comment: ok, i've just replace all ","  to "."... but now if i have " 3460" it became "3.4E3"

Answer (score 0):

You may use BigDecimal to add a "scale" to your double value :

```
Double d = 3.416436417734133;
BigDecimal round = new BigDecimal(d);
round = round.setScale(9, BigDecimal.ROUND_CEILING);
System.out.println(round);
```

Comment: if i have 10000X10000 it became 100000000.000000000 instead of 1.0E8

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code.

```
    BigDecimal aDecimal = new BigDecimal(3.416436417734133);
    BigDecimal another = aDecimal.setScale(9, aDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);

    System.out.println("another: " + another);
    System.out.println(new BigDecimal(3.7578845854848E41,new 
    MathContext(11,RoundingMode.CEILING)));
```